# $PATH not modified inside LXDE

Tags: lxde

I have a bin directory in home/pi. This is added to my $PATH when I login (by .profile), but when I go into LXDE and use LXTerminal my bin directory is no longer added to $PATH. (Sorry if this is a stupid question, this is my first day ever using Linuxy stuff).

Comment: Sorry Raspberry Pi Beta, big brother beat you :

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90509/path-not-modified-inside-lxde-on-raspbian

Comment: Hi Funky Oordvork, can you recreate the answer which worked for you and accept it then, it marks the question as resolved, and allows others with the same problem access to the solution.

Comment: Yeah, tried to do that but because I've just signed up, it won't let me. Have to wait a few more hours :(

Comment: Unless your question is about something truly pi specific, U&L will always be a better place to start asking linux questions.  P.S. Next time you cross-post, indicate that *in the post* (e.g., "Cross-posted to [link]", not after you get an answer somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry Raspberry Pi Beta, big brother beat you :

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90509/path-not-modified-inside-lxde-on-raspbian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, my last answer got forced into a comment as it was too trivial ?! So maybe if I just ramble for a bit, it will confused stack exchange's super advanced AI. Well that was me rambling and this is me providing the answer (fingers crossed) :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90509/path-not-modified-inside-lxde-on-raspbian